# How can i solve the " 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' ", problem

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, kivy

I've 2 kivy files included in the main.kv, but when i press the button in sign.kv file, it keeps on giving me this exception that i dont seem to be able to solve. please help. it seems the problem might be with ids asigned to the the textinputs which am failing to figure it out.

Main.py

```
import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass
            
    def user_login(self):
        user = self.ids.user_field
        pwd = self.ids.pass_field
        txt = self.ids.txt_field
        
        ume = user.text
        passw = pwd.text
        
        if ume == 'peter' and passw == 'peter':
                self.ids.main_screen.current = 'shop_screen'
        
        elif  ume == '' or passw == '':
            txt.text = 'username and/ or password required'
        else:
            txt.text = 'Invalid Username and/or Password'
            
        ume.text = ''
        passw.text = ''
        
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__=='__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Main.kv

```
#:include Sign.kv
#:include Shop.kv

<MainWindow>:
    id: main_win
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScreenManager:
        id: main_screen
        Screen:
            id: sign_screen
            name: 'sign_screen'
            Sign:

        Screen:
            id: shop_screen
            name: 'shop_screen'
            Shop:
```

Sign.kv

```
<Sign@BoxLayout>:
    id: signin_win
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 62
        spacing: 2
        TextInput:
            id: user_field
            hint_text: "email"
        TextInput:
            id: pass_field
            hint_text: "password"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        spacing: 2 
        Button:
            id: log_btn
            text: 'continue' 
            on_release: app.root.user_login()
        Label:
            id: txt_field
            text: ''
            color: (1,0,0,1)
```

Shop.kv

```
<Shop@BoxLayout>:
    id: shop_win
    orientation: 'vertical'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `user_login()` method of the `MainWindow` class, you try to access objects using `ids`:

```
    user = self.ids.user_field
    pwd = self.ids.pass_field
    txt = self.ids.txt_field
```

but those `ids` are not in the `MainWindow` class, they are in the `Sign` class. When you define an `id` in `kv`, that `id` gets added only to the `ids` dictionary in the object that is the root of the rule where that `id` is defined.

To fix this, you can add an `id` for the `Sign` instance that appears in the `MainWindow`:

```
<MainWindow>:
    id: main_win
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScreenManager:
        id: main_screen
        Screen:
            id: sign_screen
            name: 'sign_screen'
            Sign:
                id: sign  # added is here
```

Then you can use this new `id` in the `user_login()` method to access the `Sign` instance, and then the other `ids` within the `Sign` instance:

```
def user_login(self):
    user = self.ids.sign.ids.user_field  # now uses sign id
    pwd = self.ids.sign.ids.pass_field  # now uses sign id
    txt = self.ids.sign.ids.txt_field  # now uses sign id

    ume = user.text
    passw = pwd.text

    if ume == 'peter' and passw == 'peter':
        self.ids.main_screen.current = 'shop_screen'

    elif ume == '' or passw == '':
        txt.text = 'username and/ or password required'
    else:
        txt.text = 'Invalid Username and/or Password'

    user.text = ''  # corrected this reference
    pwd.text = ''  # corrected this reference
```

Comment: I thank you so much John,, i appreciate,, you've really helped